# Inheritance in sub target of project xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a workspace and structure like below:

[image]

Target GTSDKVN dependency:

[image]

`GTSDKVN` target has `SubViewController` class will inherit BaseViewController class. It's OK when SubViewController import `BaseLoginViewController`:

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"

@interface SubViewController : BaseViewController
@end
```

When I build `GTSDKVN` target. I facing with this problem:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_BaseViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SubViewController in SubViewController.o
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BaseViewController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_SubViewController in SubViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance...